# Google Calendar Events do not appear in Evolution

Tags: 12.10, evolution, google, calendar, google-calendar

I am trying to sync Google Calendar with Evolution email client. I am not able to see any of my calendar events in Evolution, however when in the Gnome Shell, I can see the events listed in the clock calendar.

If I add a new event using Thunderbird or on-line, the new events appears in the Clock Calendar, but again does not show up in Evolution. So Evolution is syncing, but the calendar entry does not appear in the calendar.

I can add a calendar entry in Evolution, however, the entry does not appear in Evolution, but does update in the on-line Google Calendar.

So it is syncing fine, but does not display.

In fact no calendar entries are being displayed, even if I add an entry to a Local 'on computer' calendar....

Any ideas? A known bug in this version?

Evolution Version: 3.6.2

Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit

*Also reported this as a possible bug...*

Comment: Update evolution & evolution-data-server to 3.6.4 from [bec's ppa](https://launchpad.net/~support-bec/+archive/evolution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### For 12.10

Update evolution & evolution-data-server to 3.6.4 from [bec's ppa](https://launchpad.net/~support-bec/+archive/evolution).